# (FATAL) ComputeImagesStatistics: Cannot open image QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

QGIS version: 3.16.2-Hannover
QGIS code revision: f1660f9da5
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.1.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'ComputeImagesStatistics' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'il' : ['C:/Users/srfst/Documents/Thesis/Nikos Neuropublic/Qgis/OTB Trainning/Πειραματικός αγρός.tif'], 'bv' : 0, 'out' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

2021-03-22 00:10:39 (INFO) ComputeImagesStatistics: Default RAM limit for OTB is 256 MB
2021-03-22 00:10:39 (INFO) ComputeImagesStatistics: GDAL maximum cache size is 404 MB
2021-03-22 00:10:39 (INFO) ComputeImagesStatistics: OTB will use at most 4 threads
2021-03-22 00:10:39 (FATAL) ComputeImagesStatistics: Cannot open image C:/Users/srfst/Documents/Thesis/Nikos Neuropublic/Qgis/OTB Trainning/Πειραματικός αγρός.tif. Probably unsupported format or incorrect filename extension.
Execution completed in 0.26 seconds
Results:
{'out': 'C:/Users/srfst/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_JFoxJX/07e24f0ef0184fc08c2ba87cc8a7b6bd/out.file'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'ComputeImagesStatistics' finished

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add more details: What are you trying to do using which tool. My first guess is nevertheless your filename; Does it work if you rename it from `Πειραματικός αγρός.tif` to e.g. `image.tif`? Also whitespaces in the filepath are an issue for some tools.

Comment: Can you try to rename your file with latin characters? Your issue seems to be that the path is not found and it could be related. Move it to avoid any path with spaces or special character e.g `C:/Users/srfst/Documents/your_file_renamed.tif`. You may change it again later but it's to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you guys. I use qgis 3.16 i think and the ORFEO toolbox which have in learninig part the computeImageStatistics. I am gonnaa try change name and will inform chat.